# FCKeditor: insert XHMTL to editor area

Tags: javascript, fckeditor

I have this javascript code.

```
var a = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance("FCKeditor1").GetXHTML().
a += '123';
//insert a variable into current fckeditor area
```

I got current text from editor in variable "a", changed it and now i want to insert "new" text into editor area. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `InsertHtml()`. See [docs](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/JavaScript_API)